# Get Parameter from querystring Issues Sharepoint 2010

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint-2010, c#-3.0

I have the following querystring

```
http://mydomain/mysite/SitePages/DisplayTemplateList.aspx?CustomerID=7&IsDlg=1"
```

and I'm using the following to get the value of customerid

```
HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(Request.Url.ToString()).Get("CustomerID")
```

and I'm getting null back.

Any ideas?!

Answer (score 2):

[HttpUtility.ParseQueryString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms150046.aspx) only works with the `Query` portion of a `Uri`.
Use the `Query` portion of the Request.Url instead of the full Url and you should be good to go!

HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(Request.Url.Query).Get("CustomerID")

Answer (score 2):

```
Request.QueryString.Get("CustomerID")
```